# Cypress: cy.task() with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

**What I am trying:** Pass multiple arguments in `cy.task()` command and print those argument values declared in function mentioned in `plugins/index.js` file

**Issue:** The function print prints only the first argument value and undefined for a second argument

**Code:**

```
//test file with cy.task() command

class LoginPage {
    let site = abc
    let userDetails = xyz
    openPage(env, site, userDetails) {
        cy.task('loadUserAccountDetails', site, userDetails)
    }
}

module.exports = LoginPage

// plugins/index.js file where the event is registered with declared function

const validUserDetails = (site, userDetails) => {
  console.log('--->' + site) // This prints abc
  console.log('--->' + userDetails) // This prints undefined
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config

  on('task', {
    loadUserAccountDetails: validUserDetails
  })
}
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked by passing arguments on task registered at index.js file.

```
on('task', {
    loadUserAccountDetails(site, userDetails): validUserDetails(site, userDetails)
})
```

Comment: Now Cypress has been improved and you can pass multiple elements through an object:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Arguments

Answer (score 2):

Looks like only one param is handled. But you can always pass in an **object** with the vars as properties.

```
 on("task", {
    async "rename"({var1, var2, var2}) {

 }
```

and in the `.spec` call it as

```
cy.task('rename', {var1: 'val1', var2:'val2', var3: 'val3'}, ()=>{
            console.log('renamed');
       })
```